# ES6 concatenation inside data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, eslint, static-analysis

I am refactoring old code to ES6 to not use Jquery:

```
Target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
```

However, I am getting a lint error:

> ERROR: Unexpected string concatenation. [prefer-template]

Problem is, that inside of a data attribute selector, templates are not recognized.

```
const slice = this.hash.slice(1);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name="${slice}"]');
```

It will say

> ERROR: 'slice' is assigned a value but never used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"inside of a data attribute selector, templates are not recognized"* That has nothing to do with selectors. The problem is that you are using a normal string instead of a template literal.

Comment: Use `\`` for template literals, not `'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use backticks instead of quotation marks: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

```
$(`[name="${slice}"]`)
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you. I was searching all over for that answer.